# Retrieve text from pdf in iOS, using zachron iphonepdf?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pdf

I'm using the same zachrone `iphonepdf` but I did not get the text. My text view shows nothing. What's the problem?

Here is my code:

```
NSString *text=convertPDF(@"Course.pdf");
texview.text=text;
```

But I did not get anything in text view?

Answer (score 0):

The text extractor [zachron / pdfiphone](https://github.com/zachron/pdfiphone) (I assume you meant that one) is extremely naive and makes very many assumptions.

- It ignores the PDF file structure and, therefore completely ignores whether the data it inspects is still used in the current revision.
- It ignores encryption and therefore will fail completely for many documents with usage restrictions.
- It completely ignores font encodings and implicitely assumes an ASCII'ish one --- this is fairly often true in small PDFs with English text only and not embedded fonts; otherwise the result can be anything.
- ... many many more assumptions ...

Unless one only has to deal with very simple documents and the extracted text is not really necessary for the functionality of one's code, I would propose using different code for text extraction.